# How to pass data from activity to fragment class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I created a new project tabbed view. I want three layout on my main screen 1st home 2nd category 3rd favorite. I have code of Home activity which is fragment activity the code is here

```
public class HomeFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    }
}
```

and I have another activity which is video playlist. I want to show the playlist activity in my home fragment page but I am too confused and new to Android I don't have idea what to do.

The code of video playlist is here. How can I call this code in my homeFragment class? I tried too many ways but got too confused.

Code is here which I want to implement in my home section

```
public ProgressBar nextBar;

List<String> next_title;
List title;
List vid;
List<String> next_vid;
ArrayList<Videos> videos=new ArrayList<Videos>();
Videos video;
ArrayList<Videos> toclear=new ArrayList<Videos>();
List<Videos> fav = new ArrayList<Videos>();
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
ListView listview;
Toolbar toolbar,favourite;
int menu_id;
LinearLayout layout, no_fav;
private HttpHandler parserVideo;
String nextPageToken;
String apiKey = "AIzaSyDD73ZAzcR6bXa1qOv8YZY3fFmNwfTPs48";
String url;
Main_activity_adapter search;
Main_activity_adapter adapter;

String url_home= "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=15&playlistId=PLQGGrzFoybiOks7f2BReNzNwkRw3cN6RB&key="+apiKey+"";



@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_sec);
    nextBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.nextProgress);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);
    url = url_home;
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    no_fav = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.no_favourit);
    no_fav.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    parserVideo = new HttpHandler();       
    getVideosPlaylist videosplaylist = new getVideosPlaylist();
    videosplaylist.execute();



    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    listview.setOnScrollListener(this);




}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
    final String toolbar_name = toolbar.getTitle().toString();
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(myActionMenuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            updateList();
            return true;
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

            if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                setSearch();
                search.getFilter().filter(s);


            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}// end of toolbar control

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void updateList(){

    adapter = new Main_activity_adapter(this, videos, false);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {



                                                Videos v = (Videos) adapter.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                                                Intent n = new Intent(Videos_activity.this, PlayingVideo.class);
                                                n.putExtra("vid", v.getVid().toString());
                                                n.putExtra("title", v.getTitle().toString());
                                                startActivity(n);

                                        }
                                    }

    );
}

JSONObject jp_obj;
JSONArray jar_array;

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    String toolbar_check = toolbar.getTitle().toString();

    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.listview:
            final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if (lastItem == totalItemCount) {
                if(toolbar_check!="Favourites") {
                    OnScrollList onscroll = new OnScrollList();
                    onscroll.execute();
                }
            }

    }
}


class getVideosPlaylist extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        jp_obj = parserVideo.getJsonFromYoutube(url);

        try {
            if (jp_obj.has("nextPageToken")) {
                nextPageToken = jp_obj.getString("nextPageToken");

            }
            jar_array = new JSONArray(jp_obj.getString("items"));

            if(jp_obj != null) {
                JSONObject c = jar_array.getJSONObject(0);
                String json_check = c.getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
                if (json_check == null) {

                } else {
                    title = new ArrayList<String>(jar_array.length());
                    vid = new ArrayList<>(jar_array.length());
                    for (int j = 0; j < jar_array.length(); j++) {
                        c = jar_array.getJSONObject(j);
                        String str = c.getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
                        str = new String(str.replaceAll("\\['\\]", ""));
                        String link = c.getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("resourceId").getString("videoId");
                        video = new Videos(str, link);
                        videos.add(video);
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(){
        super.onCancelled();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        updateList();
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        cancel(true);
        super.onPostExecute(s);

    }
}
class OnScrollList extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (nextPageToken!=null){
            String nextPage = "&pageToken="+nextPageToken+"";

            JSONObject next = parserVideo.getJsonFromYoutube(url+nextPage);

            try {

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(next.getString("items"));
                if (next != null) {
                    JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(0);
                    String json_check = c.getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
                    if (json_check == null) {

                    } else {
                        next_title = new ArrayList<String>(array.length());
                        next_vid = new ArrayList<String>((array.length()));
                        for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
                            c = array.getJSONObject(j);
                            String str = c.getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
                            str = new String(str.replaceAll("\'", ""));
                            next_title.add(str);
                            String nextLink = c.getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("resourceId").getString("videoId");
                            next_vid.add(nextLink);
                            video = new Videos(str, nextLink);
                            toclear.add(video);
                        }
                    }


                }if (next.has("nextPageToken")){
                    nextPageToken = next.getString("nextPageToken");
                }else if(!next.has("nextPageToken")){
                    nextPageToken = null;}
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(){
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        videos.addAll(toclear);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        nextBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toclear.clear();
        cancel(true);
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        nextBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
public  void  setSearch()
{
    search = new Main_activity_adapter(Videos_activity.this, videos, true);
    listview.setAdapter(search);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


                                                Videos v = (Videos)search.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                                                Intent n = new Intent(Videos_activity.this, PlayingVideo.class);
                                                n.putExtra("vid", v.getVid().toString());
                                                n.putExtra("title", v.getTitle().toString());
                                                startActivity(n);

                                        }
                                    }

    );
}

public void favouritList(){
    Main_activity_adapter favourit_adapter = new Main_activity_adapter(this, videos, false);
    listview.setAdapter(favourit_adapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


                                            Videos v = (Videos) adapter.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                                            Intent n = new Intent(Videos_activity.this, PlayingVideo.class);
                                            n.putExtra("vid", v.getVid().toString());
                                            n.putExtra("title", v.getTitle().toString());
                                            startActivity(n);
                                        }
                                    }

    );
}
```

Comment: create a method and directly call it from activity

Comment: how can i create method pls give me little idea

Comment: just a public method, and access it directly via fragment reference

Comment: This is too much code for readers to wade through. Would you try creating a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand that Activity contains fragments, not vice versa. So one way to make your idea come true is to make your activity contain three fragments:

- 1)Home
- 2)Category
- 3)Favorite

To send data from activity to fragment usually use Bundle object.
Then create the instance of the fragment and put bundle there by setArguments(yourBundle) method.

It is the main idea, if you want details then read official documentation and use search on SOF.

Answer (score 0):

Define variable like `public static String test="";` in `Activity` then in `Fragment` get it like `String test1=ActivityName.test;` now you have value of `test` into `test1`

Answer (score 0):

use a `Bundle`:

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("yourArg","yourType"); //this could be String, int, float,etc
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.yourContainer,fragment).commit();
```

and in your Fragment's `onCreateView`:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
```